# Why Spring Security authentication gives null

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following website under my Tomcat (both using Spring MVC)

```
www.example.com (anyone can access)
www.example.com/member (only authenticated user)
```

and my method in my HTTPErrorController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors/404.html")
    public String handle404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        return authentication == null ? defaultPage : defaultAuthorizedPage;
        // return defaultAuthorizedPage;
    }
```

Spring Security

```
<intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"
            requires-channel="https" />
<intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"
            requires-channel="https" />
```

Now if a user has logged and try to access non-existent page it should be redirected to the `www.example.com/member/home` (default authorized page) while normal user / guest should be redirected to the home page `www.example.com/home` (default page).

The issue is the authentication is always null thus I am not able to determine if user has logged. What should I do about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want error pages that are managed by the container to be protected / include Spring Security's SecurityContext you need to ensure to include the ERROR request dispatcher for the springSecurityFilterChain. For example the following in your web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: It works thanks. Where can I find the information about this dispatcher ?

Comment: This is part of the Servlet 2.4 specification. See **SRV.6.2.5 Filters and the RequestDispatcher** of https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html PS: I do not recommend filtering on includes or forwards as this will make your life unnecessarily complicated

Comment: Good Finding!! Just wanted to know what is the purpose of adding <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> here.